# How to create branch from Gitblit server?

Tags: git

I m using gitblit to maintain repository but I cant create branch from the gitblit directly. How to create branch from gitblit ?

Answer (score 1):

As seen in [this issue](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/issues/888), the natural way would be to create a branch locally, and push it.

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git checkout -b newbranch
git push -u origin newbranch
```

(with origin referencing your gitblit server)

Check though if creating a ticket on gitblit cannot create (checkout) a new branch. You would need to `git fetch` it though.